# google mobile ads url adserver

Tags: google-ads-api

I have been looking for the ad server for google mobile ads. I just can't seem to find it.

I'm adding some filters (testing) like ads.whateverdomain/* etc and was wondering if anyone knows where I can find this or even better if someone already knows?? Whether it's pattern or subdomain, any indication will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok 1 month since asking and no replies so I'll paste my findings as an answer thanks to adaway android app's [host file](http://code.google.com/p/ad-away/wiki/HostsSources):

- googleads.g.doubleclick.net
- pagead2.googlesyndication.com
- partner.googleadservices.com
- www.googleadservices.com

Adding `googleads.g.doubleclick.net` to the router's domain filtering has removed some ads from mobile applications.